# PCIe Bus error type=Transaction Layer severity=Uncorrected on shutdown on Acer Swift

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown, acer, pcie

I installed Lubuntu on an Acer Swift - installing it on the SSD already required to change the BIOS setting for the controller to AHCI.

Now I'm stuck on getting the shutdown working properly. I tried already some options in `/etc/default/grub` like

- `reboot=bios`
- `acpi=force apm=power_off`
- `pci=nomsi,noaer` (I know this should only turn off the error message)

The error that I get on shutdown is:

```
PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Requester ID)
  device [10de:id13] error status/mask=00100000/00000000
    [20] UnsupReq               (First)
  TLP Header: 40000008 000000ff a024c010 f7f7f7f7
```

After displaying that error, nothing happens and it doesn't shutdown properly.

I didn't yet mount the extra SATA - which I want to do after fixing the shutdown...

```
➜  ~ uname -a
Linux blub 5.3.0-18-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 8 20:14:06 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

➜  ~ sudo lshw
...
    product: Swift SF314-56G (0000000000000000)
    vendor: Acer
    version: V1.08
...
```

The questions I saw so far regarding this kind of error had most times "severity=Corrected" or a different "type". If you need any more information, please write a comment and I'll update the question.

How can I get this now to shutdown properly?

**Update**

```
➜  ~ lspci -nnk
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e34] (rev 0b)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:1301]
        Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) [8086:3ea0]
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) [1025:1301]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 0b)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [1025:1301]
        Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
        Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:12.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller [8086:9df9] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller [1025:1301]
        Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
        Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller [8086:9ded] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller [1025:1301]
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM [8086:9def] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM [1025:1301]
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:0034]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:9de8] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [1025:1301]
        Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
        Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:9de9] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [1025:1301]
        Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
        Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 [8086:9de0] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller [1025:1301]
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
        Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] [8086:9dd3] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Cannon Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] [1025:1301]
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9dc5] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:1301]
        Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
        Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:9db8] (rev f0)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9dbc] (rev f0)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:9db0] (rev f0)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 [8086:9db4] (rev f0)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d84] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller [1025:1301]
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9dc8] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [1025:1300]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9da3] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller [1025:1301]
        Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
        Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller [8086:9da4] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller [1025:1301]
02:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX250] [10de:1d13] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GP108M [GeForce MX250] [1025:1301]
        Kernel driver in use: nouveau
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Sandisk Corp WD Black 2018/PC SN520 NVMe SSD [15b7:5003] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Sandisk Corp WD Black 2018/PC SN520 NVMe SSD [15b7:5003]
        Kernel driver in use: nvme
        Kernel modules: nvme
```

Comment: Can you show `lspci -nnk`.

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: In my opinion, it is your nvidiacard.  but please wait, until someone is comming with more hardware knowledge than me.

Comment: In Start -> Preferences -> Additional Drivers there are three options for "Nvidia Corporation: GP108M [GeForce MX250]": "nvidia-driver-435", "nvidia-driver-430" and "xserver-xorg-video-nouveau". Currently the xorg is selected. For "Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]" it says that "This device is not working" while I'm currently in Wifi (if any of this is relevant? ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it now, so to leave the question not unanswered, I facepalm myself in answering my own question.

Things that I did now:

- Set the graphics driver to nvidia-driver-435
- Updating via synaptic package manager everything that was there to be updated

Now it shuts down like a charm.